# Blackbody radiation profile inside a heated, spherical conatiner with energy loss

Tags: thermal-radiation

My question is rather specific and perhaps not of general interest.  I'm working on a specific problem in physics.  Let's suppose we have spherical vessel with a vacuum inside.  The walls of the container are heated such that they have a fixed temperature, *T*.  The walls radiate inwardly, but energy is steadily lost from inside the vessel through a nonstandard mechanism.  My general understanding is that there should then be a gradient in the cavity temperature measured at each point, with the highest temperature at the walls and the minimum at the centre.  Is this correct?  How would one quantify this?  I would be grateful for references on it also.

Comment: How many walls has this sphere got?

Comment: I don't see how there can be a temperature gradient in a vacuum.  It seems to me that the "nonstandard mechanism" for heat removal will be at a lower temperature, and the wall of the sphere will be at a higher temperature.  If the mechanism is at the center, then the sphere will be at a uniform temperature, otherwise the sphere's temperature will vary with location.

Comment: radiation is heat transfer through space from a higher temperature to a lower one, not a temperature gradient.  Whatever your mythical object at the center is, it needs to be at a lower temperature than the walls.  You can use radiation equations to determine the heat flux.

Comment: @Mark I should have mentioned that the gradient is in the temperature of the blackbody radiation measured at each point inside the sphere.  The mechanism for energy removal is located throughout the interior.  It can be thought of as an absorption mechanism, where the absorbed radiation is then redirected back to heating the shell.  This is what keeps the whole structure in thermal equilibrium.  I agree that the shell should be at a higher temperature and the centre at the lowest (here meaning radiation temperature), but how to calculate this?

Comment: @TigerGuy As mentioned to Mark, there is no object at the centre, at least in this example.  It is the temperature of the radiation field.  Actually, the walls are not a solid material, but rather a cold plasma (dust and gas).  This is actually a cosmology problem!

Comment: If there is nothing in the center, radiation sent and received is equal for objects at the same temperature (interior sides of the wall).  I suppose you could measure the total UV radiation, and you could consider the photons to have the same temperature as the rest of the interior.  There is nothing to absorb heat, so there would be no temperature gradient.  "Temperature" in a vacuum is a difficult concept and could only in this case be taken to mean the temperature of the radiation particles.  Vacuum implies that nothing other than those particle exists there.

Comment: ... so please describe your "absorption mechanism."

Comment: @TigerGuy The absorption mechanism involves speculative physics involved with cosmology.  So fasten your seat belt!  Assume that the visible universe is surrounded by a shell of cold plasma.  The shell emits thermal radiation inwardly (the CMB).  That radiation undergoes a tired-light redshift, with the energy being absorbed into spacetime.  But there is a reverse process which releases this energy (an anti-gravitational or dark energy-like effect), which then reheats the outer shell.  So the whole system is in general equilibrium.  What would the CMB temperature curve then be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Speculative astrophysics questions cannot be answered by traditional heat transfer.

A vacuum-filled sphere will only contain the UV radiation produced by the sphere.  Since the sphere is a single temperature, all photons will be this temperature as well.

If you add speculative heat absorption and release mechanisms that involve neither traditional matter nor temperature, your solution is dependent on those (unknown) mechanisms.  Your speculative physics will need to redefine temperature to fit your model.

Engineers use known science and math to solve problems.  Scientists can exist on the fringe of observable or empirical information, but engineers stick to what is known.

Comment: Thanks, I was just hoping there could be some analogies from engineering that could assist me in modeling this.  Maybe there aren't any!